# Dockerizing Angular project giving several errors like NG8001, NG8002, NG8003

Tags: typescript, npm, dockerfile, angular17

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:18-alpine as BUILDER
RUN npm -v

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm ng -v

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY . ./

RUN npm run build

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

**Angular and node version:**

```
$ ng version
 Angular CLI: 17.0.7
 Node: 18.19.1
 Package Manager: npm 10.2.5
 OS: linux x64
 Angular: 17.0.7
 ... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
 ... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
 Package                         Version
 ---------------------------------------------------------
 @angular-devkit/architect       0.1700.7
 @angular-devkit/build-angular   17.0.7
 @angular-devkit/core            17.0.7
 @angular-devkit/schematics      17.0.7 (cli-only)
 @angular/cdk                    17.0.4
 @angular/material               17.0.4
 @schematics/angular             17.0.7 (cli-only)
 rxjs                            7.8.1
 typescript                      5.2.2
 zone.js                         0.14.2
```

**Error:**

```
#13 [9/9] RUN npm run build
 #13 0.596 
 #13 0.596 > ga-csm@0.0.0 build
 #13 0.596 > ng build
 #13 0.596 
 #13 1.612 - Building...
 #13 1.612 
 #13 12.67 ✘ [ERROR] NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:
 #13 12.67 1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
 #13 12.67 2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]
 #13 12.67 
 #13 12.67     src/app/app.component.html:0:0:
 #13 12.67       0 │ 
 #13 12.67         ╵ ^
 #13 12.67 
 #13 12.67   Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
 #13 12.67 
 #13 12.67     src/app/app.component.ts:5:15:
 #13 12.67       5 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 #13 12.67         ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 #13 12.67 
 #13 12.67 
 #13 12.67 ✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "@sedeh/differentiate"
 #13 12.67 
 #13 12.67     src/app/app.module.ts:25:39:
 #13 12.67       25 │ import { DifferentiateComponent } from "@sedeh/differentiate";
 #13 12.67          ╵                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
.............
```

I am trying to deploy Angular project using Docker In Docker (DinD) but it won't be able to build. The same as run start (npm run start). Locally it run perfectly fine.

Ps: Already have node_modules in .dockerignore